# How to create an interface in recyclerview for togglebutton.setOnCheckedChangedListener?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-togglebutton

I have a toggle button in recylerview whose setOnCheckedChangeListener needs to be set via an interface which will be called in Activity for custom code. I could find info regarding onClick Interface only. Any help regarding the code or info would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: You would do it exactly the same way as for `OnClickListener`.

Comment: How to get info to differentiate between the compound button i.e. which button was clicked (for eg. OnClick has position parameter)

Comment: Ah, OK, we're apparently talking about two different things, then. Anyway, you will be (should be, at least) handling the `ToggleButton` and its listener inside a `ViewHolder`, and you can call `getAdapterPosition()` there to get that value. Just pass that value through a parameter in your custom interface method.

Comment: I want to handle the togglebutton setOnChecked change in MainActivity. So i have created a customlistener interface in the recyclerview adapter as follow: togglebutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        customlistener.onCheckListener(compoundButton,b)
    }
});    In the main activity i will be overiding this customlistener.

Comment: Should i add the int position parameter in my custom listener?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Also, you could probably just get rid of the `CompoundButton compoundButton` parameter in your interface method, if you don't really need it in the `Activity`, which you probably don't. No sense passing stuff that's not needed.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out..it worked

Answer (score 0):

i am using an Interface for click event in my adapter and perfom the action in activity like this:-

create a Interface like this this is my Interface class:-

```
public interface FriendClickListner {
    void onClick(String type, String id);
}
```

and create its object in activity like this:-

```
private FriendClickListner clickListner = new FriendClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String type, String id) {
            // do your stuff here here after click on adapter item
        }
    };
```

and pass the clickListner object in adapter constructor like this:-

```
allFriendsAdapter = new AddGroupAllFriendsAdapter(CreateGroupActivity.this, friendsList, mUserReferance, clickListner);
```

and now in adater create a constructor of adapter like this:-

```
private Context context;
    private ArrayList<? extends ParticipantList> participantLists;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FriendClickListner friendClickListner;

    public AddGroupAllFriendsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<? extends ParticipantList> idList,
                                     DatabaseReference mUserDatabase, FriendClickListner friendClickListner) {
        this.context = context;
        this.participantLists = idList;
        this.mUserDatabase = mUserDatabase;
        this.friendClickListner = friendClickListner;
    }
```

and pass the value in friendClickListner like this:-

```
if(friendClickListner != null){
                    friendClickListner.onClick("group", participantLists.get(pos).getFriend_id());
                }
```